# What is Step 0 in Behaviorspace?

Tags: netlogo

If I check 'measure runs at every step' in Netlogo's Behaviorspace, in the output does Step 0 refer to the state of the simuation just before Go has been pressed? And then Step 1 would be as if Go had been pressed once, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

What Seth said.  But note that a "step" can be anything your want and is not linked to your `Go` button in any way.

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html :

> "The run options dialog lets you select the formats you would like the
>   data from your experiment saved in. Data is collected for each run or
>   step, according to the setting of Measure runs at every step option.
>   In either case, the initial state of the system is recorded, after the
>   setup commands run but before the go commands run for the first time."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. Step 0 is after the setup commands have run, but before the go commands have run.